# Modify SparkContext from outside __main__ file sent to spark-submit

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to package up python dependencies to send along to a hadoop cluster with `spark-submit` and I would like to do this in the DRYest way possible.

I want my `my_spark_app.py` to look like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('MyApp').setMaster('yarn-client')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sc.addPyFile('/path/to/dependencies.py')
from dependencies import DependencyManager
dm = DependencyManager(sc)

dm.register_lib('dateutil')
import dateutil

# do stuff with dateutil
```

And then `dependencies.py` is this:

```
import zipfile, os

LIBPATH = '/path/to/my/python/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/'

class DependencyManager(object):
    """
     Collects dependencies to be zipped and sent to the spark context
    """
    def __init__(self, spark_context):
        self.sc = spark_context

    def register_lib(self, p):
        libpath = os.path.join(LIBPATH, p)
        zippath = libpath + '.zip'
        zf = zipfile.PyZipFile(zippath, mode='w')
        try:
            zf.debug = 3 
            zf.writepy(libpath)
            self.sc.addPyFile(zippath)
        finally:
            zf.close()
```

This produces this (because of `zf.debug = 3`):

```
Adding package in /path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil as dateutil
Adding dateutil/__init__.pyc
Adding dateutil/rrule.pyc
Adding dateutil/relativedelta.pyc
Adding package in /path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo as dateutil/zoneinfo
Adding dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc
Adding dateutil/zoneinfo/rebuild.pyc
Adding dateutil/parser.pyc
Adding dateutil/tzwin.pyc
Adding dateutil/easter.pyc
Adding package in /path/to/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz as dateutil/tz
Adding dateutil/tz/__init__.pyc
Adding dateutil/tz/tz.pyc
Adding dateutil/tz/win.pyc
Adding dateutil/tz/_common.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my_spark_app.py", line 25
    import dateutil
ImportError: No module named dateutil
```

Somehow, calling `self.sc.addPyFile()` from within a the `DependencyManager` class does not affect the SparkContext, even though it works fine directly in `my_spark_app.py`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simple and has little to do with spark.
In here:

```
def register_lib(self, p):
    libpath = os.path.join(LIBPATH, p)
    zippath = libpath + '.zip'
    zf = zipfile.PyZipFile(zippath, mode='w')
    try:
        zf.debug = 3 
        zf.writepy(libpath)
        self.sc.addPyFile(zippath)
    finally:
        zf.close()
```

When `self.sc.addPyFile(zippath)` is called the `zf` io is still open. We just need to close it out before calling:

```
 def register_lib(self, p):
    libpath = os.path.join(LIBPATH, p)
    zippath = libpath + '.zip'
    zf = zipfile.PyZipFile(zippath, mode='w')
    try:
        zf.debug = 3 
        zf.writepy(libpath)
        zf.close() # file is now ready to add to the spark context
        self.sc.addPyFile(zippath)
    finally:
        zf.close()
```